# How to redirect example.com/x/restofurl to example.com/y/restofurl with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I have an url like `example.com/x`

How can i redirect it to `example.com/y` with htaccess.

Btw I dont want to lose rest of url.

Current .htaccess file looks like;

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]+\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution finally ; basic redirect 301 is enough in this case ;

```
redirect 301 /x /y
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/x/(.+) /y/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: didnt work, i added current htaccess file, because there are already rewrite rules maybe that's reason

Comment: Try moving the RewriteRule to the top of your HTACCESS file, right after the "RewriteEngine on".